# EJB Must have a public constructor with no parameters

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, websphere

Im getting the following error deploying an ear file in WebSphere8.5

> com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: Error while processing references for EJB-in-WAR: com.ibm.ejs.container.EJBConfigurationException: EJB class us.gov.pile.register.ejb.*RegisterMyEJB* **must have a public constructor that takes no parameters**

So i go to the class itself (RegisterMyEJB) and the constructor is already there with no parameters

```
@Stateless
@TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.BEAN)
public class RegisterMyEJB  implements IFaceEJBRemote, IFaceEJBLocal {

  /**
   * Default constructor. 
   */
   public RegisterMyEJB() {
       // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
   }
}
```

If the method is there why i'm getting this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Bean does not have a public constructor that does not take parameters' error despite clearly having one?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24868561/bean-does-not-have-a-public-constructor-that-does-not-take-parameters-error-de)

Comment: @Sampada I've looked that answer before (I've search everywhere before asking here), and I find the response ambiguos, it doesn´t clarify  why we have to use the PostConstruct anotation and why the error is appearing in first place. I'm new at this kind of stuff and we have migrate some applications from WebSpherePortal 7 to 8.5, so we didn't write any code.

Comment: I seem to recall that diagnostic can sometimes be confusingly reported by the EJB container for other reasons unrelated to the constructor.  Do you have any logic in the constructor or a static initializer that might be failing?  Are there any other "Caused by" in the logs related to this exception, or are there any FFDC log entries that occur near it?

Comment: @BrettKail says quite right thing - I have the same error and the cause was missing class dependency for my bean

Comment: @BrettKail and a.parfenov are correct. In my case, the error was occurring because of a missing jar, commonj.work.WorkManager. We're trying to move from WebSphere 8.5.5.13 to WebSphere Liberty and that jar is not provided in Liberty. There is a WARNING log message before this error message that the APPLICATION_BEAN (our ApplicationEJB.Java) dependency injection was skipped because this jar was missing. Why that's a warning and not an error is a very good question.